# Detect if a new page is being loaded

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to detect via JavaScript, whether a new page is being loaded. Let me give you an example.

Another page is being loaded after I on this link:

```
<a href='http://google.com/'>Click here</a>
```

There's no page load after I click here:

```
<a href='#anchor'>Click here</a>
```

No page load here either:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>Click here</a>
```

Yep, that's a page load. But the `href` attribute is not URL of the page being loaded:

```
<a href='javascript:void(document.location="http://google.com/");'>Click here</a>
```

This has URL in href, but it will not load a page. The `onclick` attribute is here just to illustrate the problem. In real world, the onclick event would probably by attached by event listener and canceled by `event.preventDefault()` somewhere else in the code:

```
<a href='http://google.com/' onclick='return false;'>Click here</a>
```

Now imagine, that the next page takes long time to load. What I need is a way to detect whether a new page is being loaded, after I click on the link. Or after a form submit. Or after any action that can result in page load. I know which actions to watch, but I can't be sure if they necessarily trigger the page load.

Is it even possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload) event is probably what you are looking for. Such event handlers are usually used, for example, to prevent user from accidentally leaving a page with a filled form, by showing a confirmation dialog with a custom text message.

Comment: It took a bit of hacking (the `beforeunload` is called after `click` event), but it helped. Thanks!